# Dynamic links not redirecting to app store if app not installed in ios

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase dynamic links. This is working fine as app in installed on ios or android. as if app not installed on android it redirects me to play store. but in ios if app is installed it is working fine. but as i uninstall ios app then it is not redirecting me to app. It just open deeplink. i want to open app store if app is not installed. please check if i am doing something wrong/

```
const shareLink = new firebase.links.DynamicLink(
        deepLink,
        firebaseDynamicLinkPrefix
    ).android.setPackageName(identifierAndroid)
     .ios.setBundleId(identifierIOS);

const linkk = await firebase
    .links()
    .createShortDynamicLink(shareLink, 'UNGUESSABLE')
    .then(url => {
        return url
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('ERROR', e));
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am looking for the same solution please let me know if you got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use deeplink and add your link in the link and then build a short link.